# rempsyc package nice_table() not working in r

Tags: r

I am trying to produce some APA formatted tables in R. I was trying to use the nice_table function but for some reason when i use it this is the output I get for example:

```
> nice_table(traits_sum) 

[1] header body footer col_keys caption blanks properties 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

i tried loading the packages again, calling them before the function, changing the input to the function, all I could think of but everytime that was the output I got. Does anyone know why or what I can try?

Comment: Hi Clara. Welcome to Stack Overflow. The output of a function is dependent on the input. You have shown us the function and the output, but without seeing the structure of `traits_sum`, it is impossible for anyone here to say what's going on here. Could you perhaps [edit] your question to include the output from what you get if you type `dput(traits_sum)` into your console? You can copy-paste it into your question as text. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I closed R and opened it again and It works now. No idea why, but thanks for the help :)